# Is it fine to present Median and IQR for normally distributed data?

Tags: normal-distribution, mean, descriptive-statistics, median

I have data with more than 25 variables. Some of them are normally distributed and others are not. Instead of checking each variables for normal distribution and presenting `Mean (SD)` for variables having normal distribution and `Median (IQR)` for variables that deviates from normal distribution, is it fine to present `Median (IQR)` for all the variables.

Comment: The question is too vague. Median and IQR are assessments of location and scale, resp., hence are giving indications worth reporting. They are more robust than mean and SD, meaning that for distributions with fat tails, they are less impacted by extreme values, but they are less efficient in case the first moments exist, meaning that they converge more slowly with the sample size or, equivalently, are more variable as rv's for a given sample size.

Comment: It's fine to report median and IRQ.  If you are going to report percentiles, though, what might be even more useful for the reader is to report e.g. minimum, 10th percentile, 25th, median, 75th, 90th pecentile, maximum.

Comment: Variables don't separate neatly into normal and not but even if they did: means are natural and useful for many variables that aren't normal. Consider 0, 1 variables for which almost always the median is 0 or 1 and the IQR is also almost always  either 0 or 1, which isn't informative. The mean is informative for such variables, and also natural for Poissons, exponentials, etc.  There is no obvious reason not to look at mean, SD, median and IQR.

Comment: i. You don't know what the population distribution is; failure to reject a normal does *not* mean you actually have it. $\:$ ii. There's no particular reason to discount medians and IQRs as measures if those are of interest to you, without particularly worrying about what the distribution shape might be, and similarly there's no particular reason to avoid considering means and standard deviations if those are of interest, again without particularly worrying about distribution shape. Many posts on site address this issue!

Comment: iii. There can be situations where means or medians are not suitable but symmetry vs asymmetry or normality vs non-normality are not themselves dispositive (even if you could determine these to be the case in the population)

Comment: Why are you presenting 25 variables in one table? It would be surprising if the same two statistics were good summaries for all 25 of your most important variables. Another approach would be presenting one table of numerical variables with 25th, 50th and 75th percentiles, and a separate table of categorical variables with the two most common categories and the size of the mode.